# Instead of getting two similar JFrames, I get one whith double component

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I created a `JFrame` with buttons, labels and texts and I want to show it two times when I execute the main program, so I did like that:

```
import java.net.SocketException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {
        new MyFrame("client1");
        new MyFrame("client2"); 
    }
}
```

The result: I get  two frames: one with the component of the other one inside, and one empty.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I "guess" you are using static instance fields in your MyFrame class

Comment: Ah yeah that is true !

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `static` instance fields with your `MyFrame` for your components

A component can only reside within a single container, the moment you create your second frame, the static components are removed from the first container before been added to the second.

The solution, don't do this, ever...

I assume you are using `static` because you want to access these fields from another class, in that case, you should appropriate getters in the `MyFrame` class and pass a reference of it to those classes that need it.

Alternatively, you could establish a series of observers who monitor for changes and take appropriate action, this helps to decouple the code.

Personally, if you need to modify the `MyFrame` instances in some way, I'd provide setter methods that update your components instead, as I don't like exposing UI elements without good reason, to much opportunity for others to mess with them in appropriately